# Quickly block all internet traffic with hotkey

Tags: windows, traffic

Is there any similar app for Windows? 
Pressing one button or combination to quickly **turn on/off**.

Comment: A lot of notebooks/laptops etc. offer a button quickly toggle the WiFi connection. Otherwise you'll probably need some kind of tool that directly offers this option or a software that allows you to define keybindings to run a script. This isn't going to be instant.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your question is off-topic because it is asking for a product recommendation. Many people don't realize there is a list of what is [on-topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) for this site. You can take a *[tour]* and read *[ask]* to learn more about how this site works.

Comment: Google for `windows define global hotkey` and put it together with Google for  `script to disable network adapter`. HTH

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 have an Airplane Mode that only requires 2 clicks.  Click the wireless icon on the tray, then click Airplane Mode.  However, this turns off ALL wireless communications such as Wi-Fi, cellular, Bluetooth, GPS, and near field communication (NFC).